# Display picture from access and show on form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image

I want to display picture from access and show that on a form in vb.net

I have this for display information:

```
info.TextBox5.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value
```

Now I tried something like this for pictures:

```
info.PictureBox1.Image = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value
```

But I got an error:

> Can not associate the type of Object ' System.Byte []' to type '
>   System.Drawing.Image ' .

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```vb
Using ms As New MemoryStream(CType(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value, Byte()))
    info.PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(ms)
End Using
```

Since you cannot simply assign a `Byte()` to an Image, you need to first create a `Bitmap` out of the data.

So what the above code does is:

- Creates a new MemoryStream with the `Byte()` returned by `DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(6).Value`.
- Initializes a new `Bitmap` with the data in that stream, so that you can assign it to the `Image` property of your `PictureBox`.

Comment: Got this error when i try to do that: Error   1   Type 'MemoryStream' is not defined.

Comment: Oh come on, didn't VS suggest a solution? :) Whatever, you need to use `Imports System.IO` on top of the code file.

Comment: Hahahaha i already figured that. Now i got an another error: "
Can not associate the type of Object ' System.Byte []' to type ' System.IO.MemoryStream "

Comment: And now the error is: "
The parameter IS NOT valid"

Answer (score 0):

dim str as string =DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(5).Value

if str <> string.empty then
 info.TextBox5.Text = str
end if